# Android NDK make-standalone-toolchain fails for mips

Tags: android-ndk, mips

I am running `make-standalone-toolchain.sh` to create a toolchain for the `mips` architecture, using the following command:

```
./build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh
    --platform=android-L
    --toolchain=mipsel-linux-android-4.9
    --abis=mips
    --system=darwin-x86_64
    --install_dir=/tmp/toolchain/mips
```

This gives the following error:

```
ERROR: Cant' copy from non-directory: ./sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/mips/lib
```

I've narrowed the problem down to the following lines in `make-standalone-toolchain.sh`:

```
705:  mips)
706:      if [ "$STL" = "gnustl" -a "$GCC_VERSION" == "4.9" ]; then
707:          copy_stl_libs mips         "bits"                "bits"             "../lib"       "lib"
708:          copy_stl_libs mips         "mips-r2/bits"        "mips-r2/bits"     "../libr2"     "libr2"
709:          copy_stl_libs mips         "mips-r6/bits"        "mips-r6/bits"     "../libr6"     "libr6"
710:      else
711:          copy_stl_libs mips         "bits"                "bits"
712:      fi
713:      ;;
```

The problem is that we go into the 'then' case, and it tries to copy some non-existant folders. When I modify `make-standalone-toolchain.sh` and force it to execute the 'else' case instead, the whole process works fine and the toolchain can be used as expected.

Is there a flag I'm missing to avoid the error or is this a bug with `make-standalone-toolchain.sh`?

Comment: In case this is a bug in `make-standalone-toolchain.sh` I've submitted an [Android issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77370)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the NDK, which has been resolved and added to the next release.

[Here is the Android Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77370)